# Can't migrate VM in vSphere

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

Our Vsphere interface looks like this:

[image]

So what we want to do now is above the servers folder there is a virtual machine called vvc3 (this is the VMware vCenter server appliance)
We want to move that to the ESX6 host which runs at a datacenter (somewhere else in the country)

When I want to move the VM I get this error:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/iP8xrry]

> The target host does not support the virtual machine's current hardware requirements. To resolve CPU incompatibilities, use a cluster with Enhanced vMotion Compatibility (EVC) enabled. See KB article 1003212

But on ESX6 I don't have the option to enable EVC.

Is there a way to migrate the vvc3 VM to ESX6?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is right in front of you dude, you need to deal with your EVC config, and possibly reboot your VM/s once you have sorted it out.